# Insufficient Storage Memory while installing apps

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, insufficient-memory, cyanogenmod, dialer-codes

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 International Edition operating with CyanogenMod-SnapShot-M11 11-20141008 Build. Lately when I was trying to install some Apps like Google Now Launcher or Updating Facebook and Facebook Messenger install fails and tells me:

> Insufficient Storage Memory

while I have 5 GB free of memory.

I found an Alternative Solution of fixing this by calling *#9900# USSD code, but this is failing too by throwing this message:

> Invalid MMI Code

Now I can't try the tutorial because of this thing, and I am stuck with this also I can't install applications to my Phone (not all apps but some of them).

Has this happened to anyone, or has anybody solved this issue?

Comment: Is your question about the dialer-code – or about the storage issue? In the latter case: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question, [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) should get you started.

Comment: @Izzy is related to both of the cases so thanks for the tag! :)

Comment: In that case: This is a Q&A site, which best works with *one* question per post. I'd recommend splitting it: one post for the "Invalid MMI Code", and another for the underlying issue. But then, the former will probably be closed as "off-topic", as it's not an Android specific issue. Hence it might be best to [edit] your post, focussing on the real issue (insufficient storage; point out what you've already tried from the linked tag-wiki), and making the MMI thingy a "bonus point" (one thing you've tried and failed and would be interested in why and how-to-fix).